# Provisioning profile does't include signing certificate (xcode 8)

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, xcode8, provisioning

At the moment of writing this question I am working to setup my app on my iPhone device. Initially (after a ionic/angular update in the build process) this works fine and the build and archive are successful (no signing error).

However, subsequent builds are giving me code signing errors of the following kind:

```
=== BUILD TARGET *** OF PROJECT *** WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

    Check dependencies
    Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Developer:
    *********".
    Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't include the aps-environment entitlement.
    Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'

    ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

The same error appears when I don't setup "automatically manage signing", the only difference is that it doesn't tell me the "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" is changed by the name of the provisioning profile.

The provisioning profile, however, does contain the certificate mentioned in the error so that's where I am currently stuck. The provisioning profile, in my developer account, seems correct. The build process of cordova/ionic, however, seems to ignore this.

What i would like to know is whether someone has a somewhat detailed description on how to setup the "automated signing" process (do I need to create a specific provisioning profile or does this happen automagically?) or how to setup the manual signing process where I select the provisioning profiles as I've also determined the manual process need to occur anyway for moving on to production.

Hopefully someone can help me with this.

Best regards,

One answer already given was by Jose Rojas:

Try consulting what provisioning profiles are setting in your account, the automatic signing takes a provisioning from there. see in your Team > add Account there you must be your account and the provisioning profile after if not you could download from your account in the web page https://developer.apple.com/account and set in the XCode by double click to after sign the application with this.

Comment: have you make provisioning for your app